# Rewrite Querystring which has two Questionmarks > replace 2 with &

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

for some bad reason I get an query-string returned from some external applikations which look like this:

```
/?pid=778edb836ed7803042724a674a2e5e51?QID=041349e48e1c4d46b1a2b8ff610ca19c&TransID=1374845199000003000307675&Status=AUTHORIZE_REQUEST&XID=4f75837b42ce4cca83abee43438e1d06
```

Now I was thinking there is always a TransID and I could rewrite it but I fail - my attempt looks like this:

```
Rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING}%  (.+)\?(.+TransID=.+) [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*) http://${servers:apserver}:${servers:apport}/$1?%1&%2 [P,L]
```

my Goal - Replace the second ? bevor QID by an &

Comment: Why are you using P flag and what is `${servers:apserver}` ?

Comment: P flag as apache is used as an reverse Proxy in our case and we are using a servers.txt file for dynamically sending the request to the correct host - servers.txt contains the server names. So we can generate the rewrites automatically and make our housekeeping in an Excel-Sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the \& and changeing to .* helped to fix it

```
Rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING}%  (.*)\?(.*\&TransID=.*) [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^?]*)\?([^?]*)\?([^\s]*)\s
Rewriterule ^ http://${servers:apserver}:${servers:apport}/%1?%2&%3 [P,L]
```